# NGINX--Connect to UNIX sock failed

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Checked out a few other similar issues here, but can't diagnose the issue.

My site has been occasionally going down with a 502 Bad Gateway Error.

I found the following in my error log.  Note i'm using a VPS server on Ubuntu 16.04 using Gunicorn/NGINX.

```html
2017/02/21 01:08:29 [crit] 1247#1247: *1 connect() to unix:/home/django/chrisblog/chrisblog.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 173.48.32.62, server: 45.32.201.31, request: "GET /redditclone/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/chrisblog/chrisblog.sock:/redditclone/", host: "pythoncreate.com"
2017/02/21 01:10:36 [crit] 1575#1575: *1 connect() to unix:/home/django/chrisblog/chrisblog.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 173.48.32.62, server: 45.32.201.31, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/chrisblog/chrisblog.sock:/", host: "pythoncreate.com"
2017/02/21 01:48:04 [crit] 2342#2342: *2 connect() to unix:/home/django/chrisblog/chrisblog.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 173.48.32.62, server: 45.32.201.31, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/chrisblog/chrisblog.sock:/", host: "pythoncreate.com"
```

When i go to check the gunicorn status i get the following so it looks like maybe it is failing for some reason?:

```html
 gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-02-21 01:46:08 UTC; 7min ago
 Main PID: 2245 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 21 01:46:08 mydjangoblog systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Feb 21 01:46:08 mydjangoblog systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 21 01:46:08 mydjangoblog systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 21 01:46:08 mydjangoblog systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And here is a shot of output of ps aux | grep nginx

```html
root      2341  0.0  0.1 125104  1480 ?        Ss   01:47   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  2342  0.0  0.4 125444  3152 ?        S    01:47   0:00 nginx: worker process
django    2461  0.0  0.2  16576  2000 pts/0    S+   01:57   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

any help here is hugely appreciated

Comment: Any fix for this? I am facing exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check whether "/home/django/chrisblog/chrisblog.sock" exists.